# Programmatically scroll ion-segment

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Is there any way to control scrolling on segments? In my case the slider and segments depends on each other and when you swipe slides, overflowwing segments does not slide, but active segment will be correctly choosed

My view and controller code:

```
<ion-segment scrollable mode="md" (ionChange)="segmentChanged()" [(ngModel)]="segment" color="warning">
  <ion-segment-button mode="md" value="0">
    <p>Description</p>
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button mode="md" value="1">
    <p>Interconnections</p>
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button mode="md" value="2">
    <p>Declensions</p>
  </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>

<ion-slides (ionSlideDidChange)="slideChanged()" pager="true">
  <ion-slide>
    First
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    second
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    third
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

---

```
segmentChanged() {
    this.slider.slideTo(this.segment);
}

async slideChanged() {
    this.segment = await this.slider.getActiveIndex();
}
```

The segment itself works fine, but when swiping the active segment goes behind the screen.

[image]

Comment: It might actually be possible but you haven't given me a working example to recreate your scenario. I don't want to spend time trying to figure out how to get a working example up and running, please can you expand your snippets so I can copy and paste something into a test environment that works like the animation? Example is missing styles for slide height, what `segment` is, how you define `this.slider`, etc. I had a quick go at it but I just want to test a theory not spend an hour working out how to get to a testable version :)

Comment: check this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic2-super-tabs

Comment: somebody just provided a solution that might work for you in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57122698/ionic-4-how-to-focus-the-view-of-ion-segment-when-its-clicked)

Comment: thank you for pointing to this solution, works like a charm!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am also facing the same issue and finally solved the issue with below code.

you must define the unique "id" for each "ion-segment-button"

```
<ion-segment-button SwipedTabs *ngFor="let category of tabs ; let i = index"
        value={{category}} (click)="selectTab(i)" **id="segment-{{i}}**">
        <ion-label>{{category}}</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>

.ts code 
async slideChanged() {
    this.activeIndex= await this.slider.getActiveIndex();
      document.getElementById("segment-" + activeIndex).scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'center',
      inline: 'center'
    });
}
```

hope it helps.

Comment: yeah it helps :)

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who is looking for Ionic + React + TypeScript solution:-

```
const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState<string>("0");
const sliderRef = useRef<HTMLIonSlidesElement>(null);

function onTabChange(value: string) {
    if (value === "" || value == null || value === undefined) return;

    sliderRef.current?.slideTo(parseInt(value));
}

async function onSlideChange() {
    let slideIndex = await sliderRef?.current?.getActiveIndex();

    if(slideIndex == null || slideIndex === undefined)
    return;

    setSelectedTab(slideIndex.toString());
    
    document.getElementById("tab-" + slideIndex)?.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "center",
        inline: "center",
    });
}

<IonSegment scrollable value={selectedTab} onIonChange={(e) => onTabChange(e.detail.value ?? "")}>
    <IonSegmentButton value="0" id="tab-0">
        <IonLabel>Tab 0</IonLabel>
    </IonSegmentButton>
    ....
</IonSegment>

<IonSlides ref={sliderRef} options={slideOpts} onIonSlideDidChange={() => {onSlideChange();}}>
    <IonSlide>
        <h1>Slide 0</h1>
    </IonSlide>
   ....
</IonSlides>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("your-id").scrollIntoView({
  behavior: 'smooth',
  block: 'center',
  inline: 'center'
});

<ion-segment scrollable [(ngModel)]="currentTab">
  <ion-segment-button value="subject" id="subject">
    <ion-label>ASSUNTO</ion-label>
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="book" id="books">
    <ion-label>LIVROS</ion-label>
  </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
```

Works great!

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.

It's not supported out of the box. I'm not sure if it's possible to do because, as I understand it, there is no way to get at the insides of the `ion-segment` web component unless there is an API exposed.

This encapsulation is how the components can be dropped into the page and not conflict with other stuff.

If it's super important to your project you could consider creating your own segment from copying the code of the segment and segment-button components into your own separate version?

Comment: hier is the working example just clone it `npm install` and `ionic serve` https://github.com/khashashin/swiping-segments

Comment: I mean working app with current issue of swiping segments

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, it should help [Ionic 4 Segments and Slides](https://codepen.io/brandyscarney/pen/maOabQ?editors=1010)

The .html can be like this:

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-header>
   <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>Ionic 4 Segment</ion-title>
   </ion-toolbar>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
  <ion-segment scrollable>
    <ion-segment-button value="0" checked>
      <ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Call</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="1">
      <ion-icon name="cloud-upload"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Publish</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="2">
      <ion-icon name="paper"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Topic</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="3">
      <ion-icon name="code-working"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Query</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="4">
      <ion-icon name="open"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Open</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="5">
      <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Search</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="6">
      <ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Write</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="7">
      <ion-icon name="book"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Read</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="8">
      <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Trash</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
   </ion-segment>
  </ion-toolbar>
 </ion-header>

<ion-content>
 <ion-slides>
  <ion-slide class="slide-1">
    Call
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide class="slide-2">
    Publish
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide class="slide-3">
    Topic
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide class="slide-1">
    Query
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide class="slide-2">
    Open
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide class="slide-3">
    Search
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide class="slide-1">
    Write
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide class="slide-2">
    Read
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide class="slide-3">
    Trash
  </ion-slide>
   </ion-slides>
  </ion-content>
 </ion-app>
```

Then the js like this

```
var segment = document.querySelector('ion-segment');
var slides = document.querySelector('ion-slides');

segment.addEventListener('ionChange', (ev) => onSegmentChange(ev));
slides.addEventListener('ionSlideDidChange', (ev) => 
 onSlideDidChange(ev));

// On Segment change slide to the matching slide
function onSegmentChange(ev) {
 slideTo(ev.detail.value);
}

function slideTo(index) {
 slides.slideTo(index);
}

// On Slide change update segment to the matching value
async function onSlideDidChange(ev) {
 var index = await slides.getActiveIndex();
 clickSegment(index);
}

function clickSegment(index) {
  segment.value = index;
}
```

I hope this helps anyone

Comment: Yeah I saw that already. In the example of ionic codepen there no overflow of segments. In case they change it I think they will have the same problems as me

Comment: Yh, I had the same issue, I just had to manually slide to the current segment if it is not in the view.

Comment: To scroll segment also when swiping slides replace clickSegment function with this:
`function clickSegment(index) {
  segment.value = index;
  var active = segment.querySelectorAll('ion-segment-button')[index];
  active.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", inline: "center"})
}`

Comment: @koMah when i using active.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", inline: "center"}) content goes in upperside. not working for me

Comment: Thanks @koMah your answer solve my problem with the focusing. Perfect!!!