# Ionic 4: How to focus the view of ion-segment when its clicked

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ion-segment

There are five ion-segment-button,

---

Something | Something | Something | Something | Something

---

If I click the 4th segment the view didnt follow or focus to the current segment.

[image]

Above is the current screenshot

I want the view move (to the right or focus it to the center) when the segment is clicked

HTML:

```
<ion-row>
    <!-- ion-segment -->
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-segment (ionChange)="segmentChanged()" [(ngModel)]="segment" color="tertiary" scrollable>
        <ion-segment-button value="0">
          Something
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="1">
          Something
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="2">
          Something
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="3">
          Something
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="4">
          Something
        </ion-segment-button>
      </ion-segment>
    </ion-toolbar>

    <ion-col>
      <ion-slides #slides (ionSlideDidChange)="slideChanged()" scrollbar="true" [options]="slideOpts">
        <!-- Something -->
        <ion-slide style="overflow-y: auto">
          <p>Something</p>
        </ion-slide>
        <!-- Something -->
        <ion-slide>
         <p>Something</p>
        </ion-slide>
        <!-- Something -->
        <ion-slide>
          <p>Something</p>
        </ion-slide>
        <!-- Something -->
        <ion-slide>
          <p>Something</p>
        </ion-slide>
        <!-- Something -->
        <ion-slide>
          <p>Something</p>
        </ion-slide>
      </ion-slides>   
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

TS:

```
slideOpts = {
    zoom: false
};

@ViewChild('slides') slider: IonSlides;

segment = 0;

async segmentChanged() {
    await this.slider.slideTo(this.segment);
}

async slideChanged() {
    this.segment = await this.slider.getActiveIndex();
    this.slider.update();
}
```

The found other solution but its only suitable on Ionic 3 or another ionic version..
Thank you so much for reading

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically scroll ion-segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57047922/programmatically-scroll-ion-segment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be done like this, just add an id:

```
<ion-segment-button id="something-1" value="0">
    Something
<ion-segment-button>
<ion-segment-button id="something-2" value="1">
    Something
<ion-segment-button>
<ion-segment-button id="something-3" value="2">
    Something
<ion-segment-button>
<ion-segment-button id="something-4" value="3">
    Something
<ion-segment-button>
<ion-segment-button id="something-5" value="4">
    Something
<ion-segment-button>
```

and then:

```
async segmentChanged(event) {
    this.focusSegment(event['srcElement']['children'][this.segment]['id']);
    await this.slider.slideTo(this.segment);
}

focusSegment(segmentId) {
    document.getElementById(segmentId).scrollIntoView({ 
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'center',
      inline: 'center'
    });
}
```

**NOTED:** This only works in Android as in iOS the WKWebView can't support the scrollIntoView with object parameters. There are possibilities you can put Smooth Scroll behavior polyfill to make it work.

https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll

Comment: where were you 5 days ago :D? https://stackoverflow.com/q/57047922/7986808

Comment: This works absolutely fine on latest version of Safari (iOS). Checked on Safari 14.x.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete solution:

// tab.page.html

```
<ion-header  >
 <!-- Scrollable Segment -->
 <ion-toolbar class="less-height" color="primary">
    <ion-segment scrollable mode="md" (ionChange)="segmentChanged(segment)" [(ngModel)]="segment" >
        <ion-segment-button mode="md" id="seg-1" value="0">
          <p>Description</p>
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button mode="md" id="seg-2" value="1">
          <p>Interconnections</p>
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button mode="md" id="seg-3" value="2">
          <p>Declensions</p>
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button mode="md" id="seg-4" value="3">
          <p>Phraseologisms</p>
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button mode="md" id="seg-5" value="4">
          <p>Etymology</p>
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button mode="md" id="seg-6" value="5">
          <p>Analysis</p>
        </ion-segment-button>
      </ion-segment>
</ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <ion-slides (ionSlideDidChange)="slideChanged()" class="word-slides">
        <ion-slide>
          <p>Slide 1</p>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
          <p>Slide 2</p>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
          <p>Slide 3</p>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
          <p>Slide 4</p>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
          <p>Slide 5</p>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
          <p>Slide 6</p>
        </ion-slide>
      </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

// tab.page.ts

```
 @ViewChild(IonSlides) slider: IonSlides;
  segment = 0;
  constructor() {}
async segmentChanged(event) {
  await this.slider.slideTo(this.segment);
  this.slider.update();
}
async slideChanged() {
  this.segment = await this.slider.getActiveIndex();
  this.focusSegment(this.segment+1);
}

focusSegment(segmentId) {
  document.getElementById('seg-'+segmentId).scrollIntoView({ 
    behavior: 'smooth',
    block: 'center',
    inline: 'center'
  });
}
```